# How can I copy a mesh whilst also copying all bones for the specific mesh and their weight-paints?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I wanna know if this is possible in Blender or not. Is there a way I can copy a mesh as well as it's bones on a single rig with the weight-painting intact. I'm trying to make Vulpix tails for a fan-character's model, and IO don't thing I'm willing to hand-do it over and over again.

If there' a way to do this, what is there to do?

**Version Used: Blender 2.93 LTS**

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. When you duplicate a mesh its vertex groups are also duplicated. The vertex groups store the weights for the bones. The bones are part of the armature. That's another object which also can be duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

Any time you copy a mesh, you copy its weights.  Any time you copy an armature, you copy all of its bones.  So if you want to copy a whole mesh, with a whole armature, you just select both of them and shift d duplicate.

The way that bones and weights work is that a model with an armature modifier looks for any deforming bones in that armature, and for every vertex, it looks at that vertex's vertex group weights (which can be found listed in properties/object data).  If it has vertices assigned to a vertex group with the same name as a bone, those vertices move with that bone, in proportion to their total weights to all deforming bones in that armature.  These vertex groups come along for the ride with any duplication (or any other operation)-- they are vertex data, just as attached to the mesh as vertex color, UV, or even vertex location.  They exist *only* on the mesh.

Let's say you want to make a second head on an existing model, so you duplicate the head and move it someplace.  This second head has all of its weight painting intact-- in that, it's still weighted to your original head bone!  If you make a new head bone, like head.001, and move that bone someplace, the head will need those weights redirected to that new bone.

If we want to make a second head+neck with new, copied bones, but we don't want to do any weight painting, we can do the following:

1. Duplicate the head and neck bones on your armature (in edit mode).  Be careful if they have any bone constraints, but this is fine for a simple armature.  Take note of their new names: we'll assume "head.001" and "neck.001".
2. Duplicate the head and neck meshes, then separate your duplicated mesh to a new object ('p' for me).
3. Select the new object and look on properties/object data/vertex groups.  Find "head" on that list and rename it to "head.001".  Find "neck" on that list and rename it to "neck.001".
4. Join your duplicated head back with the original object.

You now have two heads, with two new vertex groups (they get appended to the original ones when you rejoin), controlled by two separate bones.  If you didn't move the bones or the mesh, you can move them now in pose mode.  You can move them each manually to eye in edit mode on the armature+mesh, but moving the head via positioning the new bones is preferable.